# Boost link error when using "--layout=system" on VS2005

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm new to boost, and thought I'd try it out with some realistic deployment scenarios for the .dlls, so I used the following command to compile/install the libraries:

```
.\bjam install --layout=system variant=debug runtime-link=shared link=shared
--with-date_time --with-thread --with-regex --with-filesystem
--includedir=<my include directory> --libdir=<my bin directory> > installlog.txt
```

That seemed to work, but my simple program (taken right from the "Getting Started" page) fails:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Place your functions after this line
int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This fails with the following linker error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc80-mt-1_42.lib'
```

I'm sure that both the .lib and the .dlls are in that directory, and named how I want them to be (ie: boost_regex.lib, etc, all unversioned, as the --layout=system says).  So why is it looking for the versioned type of it?  And how do I get it to look for the unversioned type of the library?

I've tried this with more "normal" options, such as below:

```
.\bjam stage --build-type=complete --with-date_time --with-thread --with-filesystem --with-regex > mybuildlog.txt
```

And that works fine.  I made sure my compiler saw the "stage\lib" directory, and it compiled and ran fine with nothing beyond having the environment looking into the right lib directory.  But when I took those "testing" directories away, and wanted to use these others (unversioned), then it failed.

I'm under VS2005 here on XP.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Fast answer, for I have no access to a Visual C++ at home.*

I believe you are clashing with the "autolinking" of Boost on Visual C++ compilers.

A solution would be to disable "autolink" (see your documentation for that: A quick google search showed the macro "BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB" to disable autolinking for ALL Boost libraries), and then link explicitely your project to the right library.

I'll update this answer as soon as possible.

Comment: That worked, though now I'm getting a shared_ptr error (a BOOST_ASSERT is failing for null pointer).  I even stepped through the code and can't understand how something's not initialized.  Probably because I compiled the libraries without this flag, and am trying to compile the application with it, but that still doesn't make a lot of sense.

Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this strange (to me) linker error for my build of
Boost on Windows Server 2003 using VS2005.  I'm using similar `bjam`
command-line options as the OP was, but without the `--layout=system`
option since I don't mind the version info in them (not yet).

The *executive summary* of the verbiage that follows is: If you see
`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
'libboost_regex-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.lib'`, then you need to to specify the
same `-D` compile line options in your downstream application build as
Boost's builds do when they build the Boost Regex library. The
documentation does not state that AFAICT (as of 2010-03-23).

The details: Things I found quite helpful debugging this problem were:

1. Use the `-d+2` option to `bjam` when building. This dumps out a
   huge amount of logging about exactly what command-line options are
   being used. That was how I determined that `-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1`
   and `-DBOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK=1` were being specified on the
   `cl.exe` compile line when building the Boost Regex library.
2. Realize that you have to also supply the *same* special `-D` flags
   (use either `-D` or `/D` options which VS2005 accepts as the same
   thing) when you compile the `.cpp` files in the app that uses that
   Boost library (true for Boost Regex, and I am guessing it is true
   for others, which I have not confirmed).  That is why you will see
   a linker failure of: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
   'libboost_regex-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.lib'`, since without the
   `-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1` and `-DBOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK=1` options, the
   auto-linking will kick in when the compiler parses *your* `.cpp`
   file and `#include`'s the Boost header, the latter of which
   `#include`'s the auto-linking headers, the latter of which by
   default uses the auto-linking logic which are compiler pragmas
   that tell the linker which library to use. And guess which ones
   that auto-linking logic chooses by default? Answer: The *static*
   ones that are of the form `libblablabla.lib` and not
   `blablabla.lib` which are the import libraries you expect. This
   pragma-based linker directive logic is what had me chasing my tail
   for 3 hours trying to figure out what I did wrong on my linker
   line, when it is under C-preprocessor control in the auto-linking
   logic that did it.

Comment: Rather than the command-line option, I actually altered the user.hpp file in boost\config, since that then affects both bjam, and your own application when compiling.