# naming convention not applied for boost libraries when built using VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I just built Boost 1.54 using Visual Studio 2010. I am trying to link the built libs into my program and I am facing an issue there. The built libraries do not follow the Boost naming convention. For example, I have `boost_atomic.lib` instead of `libboost_atomic-vc100-mt-1_54.lib`
. When linking my program, VS errors out with the following error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_atomic-vc100-mt-1_54.lib'

I checked my VS project and I do not refer to this anywhere. How do I fix this? Is there a flag that will generate Boost libs with the naming convention? If yes, I can rebuild boost. If not, how do I tell Boost to pickup the libs I have?

P.S: I did try adding boost_atomic.lib to additional libraries, but it keeps asking for that specific lib( I have defined BOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS)

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458637/boost-link-error-when-using-layout-system-on-vs2005) may be useful.